# Grant statements not running in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, statements

I wrote this script to grant execute on functions on the source DB so that they are accessible from another DB using the DBlink. The scripts runs without issues, but I still cannot access the functions.

```
DECLARE 
FNC_STRNG VARCHAR2(4000);
CURSOR CUR IS 
    SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS
    WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'; 
BEGIN 
    FOR I IN CUR LOOP 
        BEGIN
            FNC_STRNG := 'GRANT EXECUTE ON schema_name.' || I.OBJECT_NAME || ' TO 
                          DB_LNK'; 
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FNC_STRNG; 
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                NULL; 
        END;
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Once I run this script...

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then when I try to access the functions using this script:

```
SELECT schema_name.func_name@db_link(param1, param2) FROM schema_name.table_name@db_link;
```

And I get this error:

```
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: The script runs without issues because you have `exception when others then null;`, which is hiding any issues from you. Take that out - or at least change it to display the errors - and see what it says. Is `DB_LNK` the user that the remote system uses to connect, from its `create database link` statement? Or is it the name of that DB link, which won't mean anything to the source DB?

Comment: I took the `exception` out and it still ran successfully. `DB_LNK` is the name of the database link schema that connects both databases that I am working with.

Comment: How are you trying to execute the functions? Sounds like you're doing something wrong there. Please update your question to include the code you're using to call one of the functions that errors

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: When I run the `GRANT EXECUTE` statement alone without a procedure then I am able to access functions from another DB.

Comment: You're running the block, and the manual grants, as the same user - as `schema_name`? have you added a debug (using `dbms_output.put_line`) inside your loop to show the object names and the actual statement it's running?

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I was running the PLSQL block on another schema thinking it will still accept it. Now that I have ran it on the actual schema (source), I am able to access these functions from another DB using the DBlink.

Comment: Well, yes - since you're looking at `user_objects`, which will only list the functions owned by the current user. Glad you got it working though.